# Are there any "sugars" for Espresso which add brace/bracket highlighting to javascript editing?

Tags: javascript, ide, macrabbit-espresso

Also, would it be possible to develop such a sugar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't quite what you are likely picturing, but my Seesaw.sugar will provide on-demand balancing using selections:

https://github.com/onecrayon/Seesaw.sugar

Comment: Hey One Crayon, just checked out your github page. Looks pretty cool. Can you attach shortcuts to your sugar actions? Also, would be great if you could provide a video showing it working... like a link to viemo or something...? Great work

Comment: @andy: You can find the shortcuts for the Sugar actions in the Actions menu. For Seesaw, just stick your cursor to the right of a bracket, hit `command option =` to select both, or `command option -` to select the opposite, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible currently.

https://twitter.com/#!/espressoapp/status/134318651783389184